# Statements not working in C. In if statement line could not executed by compiler

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, octal

I'm trying to code a C program which tries to change a decimal number to octal format.

I know there is already a feature in C programming `%o` but as a code this is not working.

So, in line no. 24:

```
div = dVar / (int)epow;
```

When I entered this line whole for function stuck. But after keep this line in `//comments` code is working. But this line is important to me for getting octal format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int dVar, power;

    printf("Enter decimal number\n"); //forget it
    dVar = 256;

    printf("%d\n", dVar);

    for (power = 0; (pow(8, power)) <= dVar; power++)
        printf("Number of digit for octal = %d\n", power);

    power--;

    for (; dVar >= 0; power--) {
        int div, epow;

        printf("hi");
        epow = (int)(pow(8, power));
        if (dVar >= epow)
            div = dVar / (int)epow; // this line is bug
        else
            div = 0;

        printf("%d", div);
        dVar -= (epow * div);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tell me where is error occurred.

An example input is 256 which is equal to 400 in octal

**Edit:** I see this method in [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Octal).

Comment: Step it in the debugger and see what happens. Could be an "Aha...." erlebnis.

Comment: The value of `dVar` is given 256. The condition `pow(8,power))<=dVar` will not be executed properly because 8^256 couldn't be held by an integer.

Comment: A suggestion: This is not the correct way to convert in any bases! Try to use division and module operator  '%'... :)

Comment: No error shown by compiler and removing 16 line make indefinite printing but adding it "hi" doesn't print as I entered in for function for checking entering in for or not.

Comment: Don't use floating-point `pow()`. Maybe `pow(8, 2)` is `63.99999432432`... Write your own **integer** function (integer result, integer arguments) to calculate powers.

Comment: @pmg And be careful about how you implement an integer-based power function.  Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 1):

**There are several errors in your code:**

1. The loop in the code:

   ```
   for (power = 0; (pow(8, power)) <= dVar; power++)
   ```

   is an error. The huge digits like 8^256 can't be held by a `signed int`.
2. Same error in the second loop:

   ```
   epow = (int) pow(8, power);
   ```

---

Use this function for conversion into octal number (from decimal):

```
int convert(int dNum) {
    int i = 1, oNum = 0;

    while (dNum != 0) {
        // Multiplying the base and the remainder of dNum (divided by 8)
        // and assigning to the oNum until zero
        oNum += (dNum % 8) * i;
        // Dividing by 8 in each iteration until zero
        dNum /= 8;
        // For bases
        i *= 10;
    }

    return oNum;
}
```